# SPring data JPA JPQL multi join entities

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpql

I want to join multiple tables by using `JPQL` query(@Query) with `one-to-many` mapping in model entities .

Eg: total 8 tables are there to join !! But I am getting error for `OneToMany` model mapping .

Below Query Works only for `@OneToOne` mapping

```
@Query("select new com.infinite.springframework.dto.WPOrderResponse(c.logo ,p.name,c.name ,ks.days)
```

FROM WPorder w , Project p ,Assignee a ,Customer c ,Domains d ,User u ,wp_kpi wk ,Kpi_Status ks
where w.project=p and p.assignee=a and w.customer=c and w.domains=d  and w.wpKpi=wk and wk.kpiStatus=ks and u.id=:userID
group by p.id ,wk.id")

Comment: Any suggestions or example pls

Comment: Please format the Query. This is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, for those complex queries in RDBMS, create a `view` in the database side firstly.

Then in your project create a read-only(in concept, most of the views in database does not support modifications) Entity for the view for queries, it is more effective.

Comment: Now I want to get these selected fields via DTO with native Query !! Need help
@Query( value= "select c.logo logo ,c.name customerName,(sum(wp.completion_percent)/count(w.wp_order_id)) completionPercent,sum(ks.days) days ,count(u.id) fteCount,count(w.wp_order_id) wpCount FROM wp_order w, Project p , Assignee a , User u ,Customer c ,Domains d,kpi_status ks ,wp_kpi wp where w.project_id=p.id and p.id=a.project_id and p.cust_id=c.id and w.id=wp.wpo_id and wp.id=ks.wp_kpi_id and a.status=?1" ,nativeQuery=true)
 public List<WPOrder> getProjectJoin(String status);